# upload file to single page app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I am trying to upload images or csv files to a `react` app. I know there is a library(react-file-upload) that does that, but I want to know how does it work. For example, if all I want to do is to upload a local `csv` file to the app and convert it to `json` format using csvtojson, what should I do?

I have a `react` component has the following:

```
<input
        onChange={e => onUpload(e.target.files[0])}
        style={{display: 'none'}}
        type="file"
      />
```

After clicking on the button, and select the file. I `console.log` it, I get the following:

```
{name: "9.jpg", lastModified: 1527215391059, lastModifiedDate: Thu May 24 2018 19:29:51 GMT-0700 (PDT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 240564, …}
```

How do I actually convert the file to a `json` array using `csvtojson`?

```
const csvFilePath='<path to csv file>'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
    /**
     * [
     *  {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3"},
     *  {a:"4", b:"5". c:"6"}
     * ]
     */ 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution by using `FileReader`.

```
class EnhancedUploader extends React.PureComponent {
        handleFiles(files) {
          if (window.FileReader) {
            this.getAsText(files[0]);
          } else {
            alert('FileReader is not supported!');
          }
        }

        getAsText(fileToRead) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
          reader.onload = e => this.fileReadingFinished(e);
          reader.onerror = e => this.errorHandler(e);
        }

        fileReadingFinished(event) {
          dataProcessor(event.target.result);
        }

        errorHandler(event) {
          if (event.target.error.name === 'NotReadableError') {
            alert('Cannot read file!');
          }
        }

        render() {
          return <Uploader onUpload={files => this.handleFiles(files)} />;
        }
      };
```

The key part of the this is at `getAsText` where I use `new FileReader`. It has a few hooks you can use like `onload` or `onerror`.

The Uploader comp looks something like this:

```
const Uploader = ({onUpload}) => {
  return (
    <Button variant="raised" color="primary" component="label">
      {'Upload'}
      <input
        onChange={e => onUpload(e.target.files)}
        style={{display: 'none'}}
        type="file"
      />
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Once the data is read, it will be a string, this is where I used `csvtojson` to read it into json, but you can use other parser to do the same job. I called it `stringProcessor`, and pass it into a react HOC, which is used in the EnhancedUploader(`dataProcessor(event.target.result)`).

```
const stringProcessor = async csvStr => {
  const jsonData = await csv({}).fromString(csvStr);

  console.log(jsonData);
};
```